# Having Permission denied error in file operation spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, jboss

Experiencing a peculiar issue with file operations in a Spring Boot project. Upon the first request, encountering a "Permission denied" error, but subsequent requests work fine.

Here are the specifics:

- Using Spring Boot 2.7.18 and Java version 17.
- Backend operations involve generating PDF reports using iText.
- A temporary file is created, its bytes are read, and then it's deleted.
- Deployment on local systems (Tomcat and JBoss) works without issues.
- However, in the client environment (deployed with JBoss and Nginx), the first API call for file generation consistently returns a "Permission denied" error. Subsequent requests function correctly.
- No access to server logs due to non-technical reasons on the client's end.

Snippet for the file generation logic :

```
@Override
public byte[] fileGenerationService(String reportName, FileGenerationGenerationCallBack reportGenerationCallBack) throws Exception {
    byte[] dataBytes = null;
    File file = getFilePath(reportName).toFile();
    file.createNewFile();
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(file)) {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        reportGenerationCallBack.generateReport(document);
        document.close();
        dataBytes = fileInputStream.readAllBytes();
    } finally {
        Files.delete(file.toPath());
    }

    return dataBytes;
}
```

Any insights on why this behavior occurs only in the client environment's initial request would be appreciated.

Comment: You've provided extremely little information to get help.  Please review the guidelines on how to ask a question and this rules for this venue *before* posting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @possum  I have updated the question please look into it.